# Rails 3 Searching through a string using an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I am attempting to do a search in Rails 3 like so.  I have a database object like so with an attribute like so:

```
@food.fruit = "Apples, Pears, Plums"
```

and I have a search that uses params from a checkbox, like so:

```
params[:search] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapefruit"]
```

Since my `@food` object above has "Apples" and the search array has "Apples" I'd like for this search to be successful.  However I am having trouble having this work properly.

My initial thought was to do something like

```
@results = Food.where("fruit LIKE ?", "%params[:search]%")
```

or

```
@results = Food.where("fruit IN ?", params[:search])
```

But the first only works if the `params[:search]` contains ONLY the `@food.fruit` elements and no others. The second doesn't work at all.

My last ditch resort is to do something like

```
@results = Array.new
params[:search].each do |search|
  @results << Food.where("fruit LIKE ?", search)
end
```

but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.  Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is some SQL like this:

```
WHERE LOWER(fruit) LIKE '%apples%'
   OR LOWER(fruit) LIKE '%oranges%'
   OR LOWER(fruit) LIKE '%bananas%'
   OR LOWER(fruit) LIKE '%grapefruit%'
```

Note that `LIKE` is not necessarily case insensitive so pushing everything to lower case (or upper case) is generally a good idea.

That's simple enough but saying `x.where(...).where(...)...` connects the conditions with `AND` when you want `OR`. One way is to build the first argument to `where` as a string by pasting together the right number of `"LOWER(fruit) LIKE ?"` strings to match the number of elements in `params[:search]`:

```
@results = Food.where(
    (["LOWER(fruit) LIKE ?"] * params[:search].length).join(' OR '),
    *(params[:search].map { |s| '%' + s.downcase + '%' })
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes complete sense to me, and totally should work...and it does, when the params[:search] has one item in it.  But when I make that array 2 or more, it throws me the "wrong number of bind variables (1 for 3)" error, with the 3 being how many items are in the array.  This really doesn't make sense as to why this is happening.

Comment: @Ryan: You could try adding a splat to un-array the bind variable array (as in my fixed answer).

Comment: ahh perfect...thank you! I wish I could be as brilliant with my SQL as you! Any tips to learn more?

Comment: @Ryan: Practice, make mistaeks, and learn from them. And get familiar with whatever documentation is available. Answering questions on SO helps too :) And there are a lot of people around here that are better at all this stuff than I am.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you're doing 5 separate searches.  While making 5 separate SQL queries might not be the answer, you could always join the array, like:

```
scope :search_fruit, lambda {|*fruits|
  where fruits.flatten.map {|fruit| arel_table[:fruit].matches("%#{fruit}%") }.inject(&:or)
}
```

and

```
Food.search_fruit(params[:fruit])
```